# How can I constraint this?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to create a constraint that only accept in the field IndPregnancy 'Yes' or 'No'. But this only apply when the field sex is 'F'.

I have this:

```
ALTER TABLE CONTROLPACIENT ADD CONSTRAINT controlpacient_c3
CHECK IndPregnancy IN (‘Yes’, ‘No’)
```

So, how can i put another constraint because sex is in another table. Thanks.

Comment: If you can copy the `sex` column into your `CONTROLPACIENT` table,  you could use the check constraint method. You might add `sex` to the FK constraint to the other table (assuming there is a relational constraint already) which will ensure that they must be in sync. Of course, this would require a change to any applications that update the data, or possibly triggers. This solution may or may not be more complicated than warranted by your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `sex` can only be `M` or `F` and that `indPregnancy` is supposed to be `NULL` when `sex` is `M`

```
CHECK( (sex = 'F' and indPregnancy IN ('Yes', 'No')) or
       (sex = 'M' and indPregnancy IS NULL ) );
```

If `sex` is a column in a different table, you realistically can't create a constraint to enforce this rule.  If you were really determined, you could create a fast-refreshable materialized view that joined the two tables together and create a constraint on that.  Or if you're willing to accept a 90% solution, you could create a trigger on `ControlPacient` that queried `Pacient` and raises an exception if the rule is violated.  But such a trigger would fail to detect issues created by multiple sessions modifying data at the same time unless you implement a lot of additional serialization which is why it's a 90% solution rather than a 100% solution.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that sex is in another table called PACIENT, so how can i refer to that field to check both.

Comment: @Danielesk - Updated my answer.  Realistically, if `sex` is a column in a different table, you're not going to be able to create a constraint that enforces the rule.